# MySQL sub-query performance issue with EF6

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, database-performance

I am having an issue where MySQL takes 30+ seconds running the following query. Flattening the sub-query ellimiates the problem. It is unfortunate that Entity Framework (or MySql.Data.Entity implementation) produces a terrible projection too.

Do I need to remove all EF projections, or is there another option available to me?

Versions:

- Entity Framework v6.1.3
- MySQL v5.7.15
- MySql.Data.Entity v6.9.9

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Journals(
    GeneralLedgerAccountId varchar,
    Synchronized bit,
    Number int
)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Journals
    WHERE GeneralLedgerAccountId = 'abc123'
    AND Synchronized = 1
    ) AS x
ORDER BY 
x.Number DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

For reference, the following equivalent query takes under a second:

```
select * from Journals 
where `GeneralLedgerAccountId` = 'abc123' 
and `Synchronized` = 1 limit 1
```

Query plan:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "55155.11"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "Journals",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "PRIMARY"
        ],
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "GeneralLedgerAccountId"
        ],
        "key_length": "98",
        "ref": [
          "const"
        ],
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 273272,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 27327,
        "filtered": "10.00",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "500.71",
          "eval_cost": "5465.44",
          "prefix_cost": "55155.11",
          "data_read_per_join": "9M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "GeneralLedgerAccountId",
          "Id",
          "Number",
          "Synchronized"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`mydb`.`journals`.`GeneralLedgerAccountId` <=> 'abc123') and (`mydb`.`journals`.`Synchronized` = 1))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i am also facing same issue, did you found the solution ?

Comment: What indexes do you have?  The two queries are _not_ equivalent -- Leaving out the `ORDER BY` makes the `LIMIT` unpredictable and speeds up the query.